# Share publicly multiple files at once in Google Cloud Platform storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I was used to manually upload contents to Google Cloud Platform storage and share publicly multiple files at once (select all checkbox then Share publicly button).

Now the Share Publicly button is gone so I have to manually check every single file. Sounds like a big regression.
Anyone knows another solution to automate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use gsutil:

```
gsutil acl set public-read gs://your-bucket/*
```

If it's a large number of objects, use the -m option to do the work multi-threaded:

```
gsutil -m acl set public-read gs://your-bucket/*
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for your answer. I'm not used to gsutil tool but I think it is great for my needs.

Comment: In case it helps other users: you can add -r flag to do it recursively: gsutil [-m] acl set -r public-read gs://your-bucket/*